# On/In my last holiday I went to Greece?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, british-english

I've got difficulties in using prepositions. I'm not sure how to say it correctly.

> On my last holiday I went to Greece.
>   In my last holidays I went to Greece.
>   In my last holidays I was in Greece.

What would a native speaker of British English say?

Comment: You can use _on_ or _during_. You also might want to check out [ell.se].

Comment: If you were in Greece during the entire holiday, the usual form would be: "For my last holiday I went to Greece". If it was just something you did, let's say on a grand tour of southern Europe, you might say "during my last holiday, I went to/was in Greece". "On" might be used, for something you did during the holiday, but in this particular example feels a bit awkward. "In" is not at all idiomatic here.

Comment: In the US, the preposition might well be omitted in conversation.

Comment: I think the meaning of "holiday" is different in the U.K. and the U.S. In British English, "holiday" can mean what in the U.S. is called a vacation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on exactly what you're trying to say.

We do not use *in* with *holiday*, except in the case of *in the holidays*, meaning "at some point during the period of time referred to as *the holidays*". If you talk about "in my holiday", you are not using idiomatic English - and definitely not British English. "In my holidays" is meaningful, but only to refer to a period of time like the summer holidays, the time pupils and students have without school in the summer. However, it's still an unusual turn of phrase. "In the summer holidays" is, however, idiomatic.

The distinction between ***holiday*** and ***holidays***, in British English, is slightly more complex than singular versus plural. The idea of *holiday* can mean either when you go away from home for leisure reasons, in which case you would use an article:

> "I want **a holiday** in Spain."

Or some other determiner:

> "During **my holiday** in Spain."
>   "During **my holiday** to Spain."

I'll get back to that choice between *in* and *to* later. You can also use *on*, rather than a determiner, in order to create a phrase that can be used to describe a state or as an adverbial phrase:

> "I had fun **on holiday in Spain**."
>   "I won't be replying to emails next, as I will be **on holiday**."

If you use *holiday* in this sense, and pluralise it to *holidays*, you are referring to multiple different trips.

> "I had **four holidays** last year, to Spain, to Bermuda, and twice to Ireland."

Of course, a holiday need not be to another country.

> "I'm planning **two holidays** this year, one in Scotland and once to the Lake District."

The other meaning, referring to scheduled time off, is most familiar in reference to the six gaps in school each year - the summer holidays (usually but not always plural), the Easter holiday or holidays (can be either, in my experience), and the Christmas holiday or holidays (likewise), along with the three half-term holidays, each usually referred to as *a holiday* rather than each being *holidays* - each is a week long. You can talk about *the school holidays* and you might be referring to all six together, or to just one instance.

This meaning is also used in relation to adults for their time off work, especially where it is scheduled and the whole workplace shuts down. We have a system of legally guaranteed *paid annual leave*, but people will often refer to such leave as *holiday*, and having *paid holidays*.

In this sense of "time off", that may or may not include "going away", we can use the work *in* for the things that happened.

> "I'm going to play a lot of Fortnite **in the holidays**."

But we can also use *during*.

> "I'm going to miss you **during the holidays**."

For the sense of a trip away, we wouldn't use *in*. We would tend to use *on*, *for*, and *during*, with slightly different meanings. If we did something *for* a holiday, that means it is the thing that represents the whole holiday.

> **For** my next holiday, I'm going white-water rafting.

That means that the entire trip is based around white-water rafting.

> **For** my next holiday, I'm thinking of going to Spain.

That means that you are consider Spain as the destination of your next leisure trip away.

*On* holiday is either used as an adjectival phrase to refer to the state of being on a leisure trip away, or to refer to things that happen while taking such a trip.

> Don't try to talk to me about work, I'm **on holiday**!
>   While I was **on holiday**, I could just forget about work.

*During* a holiday is just a qualifier that says things happened in the course of such a trip, much like *during* for the other use of *holiday*.

> During my next holiday, I want to try white-water rafting.

This means that you want your next holiday to involve white-water rafting, but not necessarily to be entirely based around it.

So, to get back to your specific question, any of the following might be appropriate, but they have meanings that are different, subtly or not so subtly:

> For my last holiday, I went to Greece.
>   During my last holiday, I was in Greece.
>   In the holidays, I went to Greece

Comment: Super detailed answer ! +1 By the way just for information I think the op account have been deactivated.

Comment: @Ced: Answers aren't just for the people asking the questions - other people find the questions, and it's better if they find the answers to. Any question that shouldn't be closed should be answered, eventually.

Comment: Of course, I didn't and won't flag this question for any reasons. I simply realised that the op account have been deactivated so I wanted to tell it to you.

Comment: They may actually never have had an account on this SE, given that the question was migrated.

Comment: you are right, thanks for the details I now understand better how the op could have ask a question without having a account on ell

Answer (score 0):

I think the best to use is none of your three propositions, I would rather say:

> For my last holiday I went to Greece.

**Holiday** as a singular noun commonly refers to a specific day or event, which is your case because you are talking about your *last holiday* :

> It’s a public **holiday** on Monday, isn’t it, so I suppose the banks’ll
>   be closed?
>
> She seems very tired and upset at the moment. She needs a **holiday**.
>
> We booked a **holiday** online yesterday – two weeks in Greece.

Source: [cambridge_dictionary_british-grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-nouns/holiday-and-holidays) and [oxfordlearnersdictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/holiday_1)